# problems with overloaded function members C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have declared a class as

```
class DCFrameListener : public FrameListener, public OIS::MouseListener, public OIS::KeyListener  
{
    bool keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent & kEvt);
    bool keyReleased(const OIS::KeyEvent &kEvt);

//*******some code missing************************   
};
```

But if i try defining the members like this

```
bool DCFrameListener::keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent kEvt)
{
    return true;
}
```

The compiler  refuses with this error

```
error C2511: 'bool DCFrameListener::keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent)' : overloaded member function not found in 'DCFrameListener'  
see declaration of 'DCFrameListener'
```

Why is  this happening, yet  i declared the member **keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent)** in my function declaration.

any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ok, stupid mistake. Didn't see it comming :)

Comment: Stupid mistakes are OK, as long as they're temporary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The one in the declaration has a reference:

```
bool keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent & kEvt);
                                    ^!
bool DCFrameListener::keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent kEvt)
                                                    ^?
```

Comment: Funny how the eye can gloss over such a thing.